# Convert UTF string to Chinese Language from JSON response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, utf

I tried everything to convert JSON response to Chinese language but not getting any success. I need to display those string in uilabel.

This is the response I'm getting:

```
sentence = "\U00e6\U201a\U00a8\U00e5\U00a5\U00bd\U00e3\U20ac\U201a";
pinyin = "n\U00c3\U00adn h\U00c4\U0192o"
```

Converting sentence's string should be like **您好** but I'm getting **æ‚¨å¥½ã€‚**

For **pinyin** I'm getting exactly right string [[nín hăo]] in label without converting but for sentence it gives me wrong value.

I'm using XCode 7.1 and my deployment target is 8.0.

Comment: add some more code.. also I think you should use utf encoding for sentence..

Comment: like this NSString* newStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sentence];

Comment: Please do not add your deadlines to questions. All questions are of equal importance, and in any case it is just noise that someone has to edit out. Questions are here for perpetuity, not just until Monday.

Comment: @AshishP. Thansk, I used what you said,
    NSString *sentence = [[dic valueForKey:@"sentence"] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *newStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sentence.UTF8String];
    cell.lblSentence.text = newStr;
but getting this: æ‚¨å¥½ã€‚

Comment: @halfer I will keep it in mind.

Comment: If you roll back good edits again, I will flag this for a moderator.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You should parse a JSON response with NSJSONSerialization, and what you get is NSString containing Unicode. No UTF-8 anywhere.

Comment: @Nij: Doesn't it occur to you that converting an NSString to UTF8 and then converting it back to NSString is utter nonsense?

Comment: @gnasher729 I tried all the possible way because i've no control over web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thanks all for helping and trying :) i ended up solving my own problem. What I did is directly put dict value to label text rather than passing from NSString. Taking it into string will give me value like **æ‚¨å¥½ã€‚**

Here is what i've done.

```
cell.lblWord.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Word: %@",[[dic objectForKey:@"cat"]objectForKey:@"chart"]];
```

It's strange but true, tried before but wasn't working.